# Automate the process of running an excel macro on Sharepoint

Tags: automation, microsoft-excel, macros, sharepoint

Is there any way to automate the process of running an excel macro from an excel file in SharePoint without having to do it manually every day? From my understanding, Sharepoint does not have this feature currently.